# Python coroutine time slicing

Tags: python, coroutine

I am learning how to use coroutines from here  and the article an video describes the following as an example

> Chess master Judit Polgár hosts a chess exhibition in which she plays
>   multiple amateur players. She has two ways of conducting the
>   exhibition: synchronously and asynchronously.
>
> Assumptions:
>
> ```
> 24 opponents
> Judit makes each chess move in 5 seconds
> Opponents each take 55 seconds to make a move
> Games average 30 pair-moves (60 moves total)
> ```
>
> Synchronous version: Judit plays one game at a time, never two at the
>   same time, until the game is complete. Each game takes (55 + 5) * 30
>   == 1800 seconds, or 30 minutes. The entire exhibition takes 24 * 30 == 720 minutes, or 12 hours.
>
> Asynchronous version: Judit moves from table to table, making one move
>   at each table. She leaves the table and lets the opponent make their
>   next move during the wait time. One move on all 24 games takes Judit
>   24 * 5 == 120 seconds, or 2 minutes. The entire exhibition is now cut
>   down to 120 * 30 == 3600 seconds, or just 1 hour.

The write up is taken from here https://youtu.be/iG6fr81xHKA?t=4m29s

If i were to write the code for the chess exhibition, my program would contain 24 coroutines and must finish within 5 seconds and move to the next coroutine.

My question therefore is, in python is writing 24 functions that pretty much does the same thing considered bad coding practice and if so what can be done about it?.

Edit

From this example https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/examples/other/coroutines-and-futures.py

I see that we can do 24 functions.

Comment: `24 functions` - no. You need 1 function and 24 sets of arguments corresponding to 24 games.

Comment: @Poolka that's interesting. Could you make a dummy snippet showing what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of implementing it:

```
import asyncio


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name: str, seconds_per_turn: float):
        self.name = name
        self.seconds_per_turn = seconds_per_turn
        self.busy = asyncio.Condition()

    async def move(self, game):
        await self.busy.acquire()
        print(f'game {game.game_number} player {self.name} begins {self.seconds_per_turn} second move')
        await asyncio.sleep(self.seconds_per_turn)
        print(f'game {game.game_number} player {self.name} ends {self.seconds_per_turn} second move')
        self.busy.release()


class Game:
    def __init__(self, game_number: int, player1: Player, player2: Player, number_of_turns: int):
        self.game_number = game_number
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.number_of_turns = number_of_turns

    async def start(self):
        print(f'game {self.game_number} started')
        for turn in range(1, self.number_of_turns + 1):
            print(f'game {self.game_number} turn #{turn}')
            await self.player1.move(self)
            await self.player2.move(self)
        print(f'game {self.game_number} ended')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    synchronous = False
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    judit = Player('judit', 5)
    for i in range(1, 25):
        opponent = Player(f'opponent {i}', 55)
        game = Game(i, judit, opponent, 30)
        if synchronous:
            loop.run_until_complete(game.start())
        else:
            asyncio.ensure_future(game.start())
    loop.run_forever()
```

**Output:**

```
game 1 started
game 1 turn #1
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 2 started
game 2 turn #1
game 3 started
game 3 turn #1
game 4 started
game 4 turn #1
game 5 started
game 5 turn #1
game 6 started
game 6 turn #1
game 7 started
game 7 turn #1
game 8 started
game 8 turn #1
game 9 started
game 9 turn #1
game 10 started
game 10 turn #1
game 11 started
game 11 turn #1
game 12 started
game 12 turn #1
game 13 started
game 13 turn #1
game 14 started
game 14 turn #1
game 15 started
game 15 turn #1
game 16 started
game 16 turn #1
game 17 started
game 17 turn #1
game 18 started
game 18 turn #1
game 19 started
game 19 turn #1
game 20 started
game 20 turn #1
game 21 started
game 21 turn #1
game 22 started
game 22 turn #1
game 23 started
game 23 turn #1
game 24 started
game 24 turn #1
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 2 player judit begins 5 second move
game 2 player judit ends 5 second move
game 2 player opponent 2 begins 55 second move
game 3 player judit begins 5 second move
game 3 player judit ends 5 second move
game 3 player opponent 3 begins 55 second move
game 4 player judit begins 5 second move
game 4 player judit ends 5 second move
game 4 player opponent 4 begins 55 second move
game 5 player judit begins 5 second move
game 5 player judit ends 5 second move
game 5 player opponent 5 begins 55 second move
game 6 player judit begins 5 second move
game 6 player judit ends 5 second move
game 6 player opponent 6 begins 55 second move
game 7 player judit begins 5 second move
game 7 player judit ends 5 second move
game 7 player opponent 7 begins 55 second move
game 8 player judit begins 5 second move
game 8 player judit ends 5 second move
game 8 player opponent 8 begins 55 second move
game 9 player judit begins 5 second move
game 9 player judit ends 5 second move
game 9 player opponent 9 begins 55 second move
game 10 player judit begins 5 second move
game 10 player judit ends 5 second move
game 10 player opponent 10 begins 55 second move
game 11 player judit begins 5 second move
game 11 player judit ends 5 second move
game 11 player opponent 11 begins 55 second move
game 12 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #2
game 12 player judit ends 5 second move
game 12 player opponent 12 begins 55 second move
game 13 player judit begins 5 second move
game 2 player opponent 2 ends 55 second move
game 2 turn #2
game 13 player judit ends 5 second move
game 13 player opponent 13 begins 55 second move
game 14 player judit begins 5 second move
game 3 player opponent 3 ends 55 second move
game 3 turn #2
game 14 player judit ends 5 second move
game 14 player opponent 14 begins 55 second move
game 15 player judit begins 5 second move
game 4 player opponent 4 ends 55 second move
game 4 turn #2
game 15 player judit ends 5 second move
game 15 player opponent 15 begins 55 second move
game 16 player judit begins 5 second move
game 5 player opponent 5 ends 55 second move
game 5 turn #2
game 16 player judit ends 5 second move
game 16 player opponent 16 begins 55 second move
game 17 player judit begins 5 second move
game 6 player opponent 6 ends 55 second move
game 6 turn #2
game 17 player judit ends 5 second move
game 17 player opponent 17 begins 55 second move
game 18 player judit begins 5 second move
game 7 player opponent 7 ends 55 second move
game 7 turn #2
game 18 player judit ends 5 second move
game 18 player opponent 18 begins 55 second move
game 19 player judit begins 5 second move
game 8 player opponent 8 ends 55 second move
game 8 turn #2
game 19 player judit ends 5 second move
game 19 player opponent 19 begins 55 second move
game 20 player judit begins 5 second move
game 9 player opponent 9 ends 55 second move
game 9 turn #2
game 20 player judit ends 5 second move
game 20 player opponent 20 begins 55 second move
game 21 player judit begins 5 second move
game 10 player opponent 10 ends 55 second move
game 10 turn #2
game 21 player judit ends 5 second move
game 21 player opponent 21 begins 55 second move
game 22 player judit begins 5 second move
game 11 player opponent 11 ends 55 second move
game 11 turn #2
game 22 player judit ends 5 second move
game 22 player opponent 22 begins 55 second move
game 23 player judit begins 5 second move
game 12 player opponent 12 ends 55 second move
game 12 turn #2
game 23 player judit ends 5 second move
game 23 player opponent 23 begins 55 second move
game 24 player judit begins 5 second move
game 13 player opponent 13 ends 55 second move
game 13 turn #2
game 24 player judit ends 5 second move
game 24 player opponent 24 begins 55 second move
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 14 player opponent 14 ends 55 second move
game 14 turn #2
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 2 player judit begins 5 second move
game 15 player opponent 15 ends 55 second move
game 15 turn #2
game 2 player judit ends 5 second move
game 2 player opponent 2 begins 55 second move
game 3 player judit begins 5 second move
game 16 player opponent 16 ends 55 second move
game 16 turn #2
game 3 player judit ends 5 second move
game 3 player opponent 3 begins 55 second move
[...]
```

By setting `synchrounous` to `True` the first game has to finish before the second game will start.

**Output with `synchrounous = True`:**

```
game 1 started
game 1 turn #1
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #2
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #3
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #4
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #5
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #6
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #7
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #8
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #9
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #10
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #11
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #12
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #13
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #14
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #15
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #16
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #17
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #18
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #19
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #20
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #21
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #22
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #23
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #24
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #25
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #26
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #27
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #28
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #29
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 turn #30
game 1 player judit begins 5 second move
game 1 player judit ends 5 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 begins 55 second move
game 1 player opponent 1 ends 55 second move
game 1 ended
game 2 started
game 2 turn #1
game 2 player judit begins 5 second move
game 2 player judit ends 5 second move
game 2 player opponent 2 begins 55 second move
game 2 player opponent 2 ends 55 second move
game 2 turn #2
game 2 player judit begins 5 second move
game 2 player judit ends 5 second move
game 2 player opponent 2 begins 55 second move
game 2 player opponent 2 ends 55 second move
game 2 turn #3
game 2 player judit begins 5 second move
[...]
```